# is it possible in a custom post, create custom fields as well whitin?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

Well, I created my custom post, but I am wondering why is this if not for a customizable post page? so, I am guessing in some way, I could add new fields on this custom post and publish it as if it were a normal post WITHOUT installing Advance Custom Fields plugin and so on, just one simple done by myself.

DO anybody know any about this??

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome at WPSE. I am sorry but I have some difficulties understanding your question. Could you maybe find someone to help you with your english? What I *think* I have understood is that you want to add custom fields to a custom post type?

Comment: yes, is exactly that, I was wondering why wordpress let you create a custom type of post... if not to create it with custom fields as well... Could you help me with that?

Comment: You *can* add custom field to custom post types (CPT). See [the Codex page on Custom Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields), to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `add_meta_box`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

```
// Metabox actions
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'metabox_create' ); // create
add_action( 'save_post', 'metabox_save' ); // save

// Create metabox
function metabox_create() {
  add_meta_box( 'metabox_name', 'Metabox Title', 'metabox_content', 'my_custom_post_type', 'normal', 'high' );
}

// metabox content
function metabox_content() {
  global $post;

  // custom field data
  $custom = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
  $field_name = $custom['field_name'][0];

  // contents
  ?>
  <label for="field_name">Field name</label>
  <input name="field_name" id="field_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $field_name ); ?>" />
  <?php
}

// save metabox fields
function metabox_save() {
  global $post;

  // Ignore autosave
  if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && true === DOING_AUTOSAVE ) { return; }

  // Save post meta.
  update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'field_name', $_POST['field_name'] );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think is similar, how can I test it? where should I put this code? I got an undefined function error when I just copy on my main plugin file

Comment: I revised the code. Originally written from memory, but forgot the add_action calls. What function is it saying is undefined? You also might want to either move these calls into a class or prefix the function names with the name of your post type to avoid conflicts.